# Wordpress ACF passing a variable as a value into args array

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create a dynamic posts layout. In the backend, I have a field where I enter the slug of the post collection I want to pass in.

The $subfield value is recipe. For some reason, when I write 'post_type' => $subfield it's not working. It only works when I hardcode it. Any insight as to why my $subfield variable is empty when I pass it as a value to 'post_type'

```
<?php 



if ( 
get_row_layout() == 'list_posts' ) {

// $subfield = the_sub_field( 'custom_post_type' );
// this variable has a string value of recipe in the backend

    
$args = array(
  'post_type'   => 'recipe' //works when hardcoded, not when $subfield is passed
 );


 $the_query = new WP_Query($args );

 if (
 $the_query->have_posts() )
 :while (
 $the_query->have_posts() )
 : $the_query->the_post();
 ?>

  <a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>">
     <?php echo the_title();?>
  </a>

  

  <?php wp_reset_postdata();
      endwhile;
      endif;
    } 

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [ACF document](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_sub_field/): `the_sub_field()` **displays** the value of a specific sub field value from a Repeater or Flexible Content field loop. This function is essentially the same as `echo get_sub_field()`. So, it won't return the expected value to the `$subfield` variable. Let's use the `get_sub_field()` instead:

```php
$subfield = get_sub_field( 'custom_post_type' );
```

There is an implicit convention in the WordPress world: the names of the functions that display values will begin with `the_`, and the names of the functions that return values will begin with `get_`.